# Changing the value of the other Cell base on the month you entered

Tags: vba, excel

So I have an Excel file with 2 sheets with the name of **YEAR sheet** and **monthly report Sheet**, Is that possible to change the value of F21:F29 of **Monthly report Sheet** base on the date or current date today., for ex. Today is February, the data that will be place on F21:F29 of **Monthly report sheet** is the February Column or the F21:F29 of the **YEAR Sheet**., and when the current month is March the data that will be place on F21:F29 of **Monthly report sheet** is the March Column or the G21:G29 of the **YEAR Sheet**.

Thank you so much Guys, GoodBless[image][image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Better put screenshot of your data.

Comment: What is your approach? Code? What is your code so far? Formulas? What have you come up with? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Ma'am/Sir @harun24hr here are my screen shots for sheet 1 and sheet 2.

Comment: @rabal See my answer below and let me know it works for you or not?

Comment: @harun24hr Good day sir :) I have a follow up question regarding on the procedure on excell.., your codes work and now, i want to get the grand total of the activity base on the selected month., Ex. the you select is Feb. the system will automatically add the total of Feb. and the total of Jan. same case on march., only the previous month will be added to the grand total see the updated post.. thank you.. GODBLESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your given screenshot put below formula to `F21` cell of `Monthly Report Sheet` then drag and down as need.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('YEAR Sheet'!$E$21:$P$32,ROWS($E$21:$E21),MATCH(LEFT($F$3,3),'YEAR Sheet'!$E$19:$P$19,0)),"")
```

***Note:*** If data starts from different cell in `YEAR sheet` then you have to modify formula to adjust will data ranges.

Comment: Good day sir :) I have a follow up question regarding on the procedure on excell.., your codes work and now, i want to get the grand total of the activity base on the selected month., Ex. the you select is Feb. the system will automatically add the total of Feb. and the total of Jan. same case on march., only the previous month will be added to the grand total see the updated post.. thank you.. GODBLESS.

Comment: @rabal Then you have to use `sumifs()` function. Share your sample excel file via google drive or dropbox then give me download link in this comment. I will do that for you.

Comment: this is the downloadable link sir. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTLOjzilJrIia8Vn6Q5RRAa754yo2Kb50z81XBtS3ho/export?format=xlsx

Comment: It prompt for request access. Please share it as public.

Comment: Good Day sir. Already saw the updated file., Please Check your gmail for some concern. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX MATCH. As long as the cells with the months in are all formatted as dates it'll work

Comment: Can you show here Ma'am/Sir how this INDEX MATCH work ? Thanks

Comment: =INDEX ( the columns where the data you want , MATCH ( your lookup cell with the month in , the columns where you are looking up the data , 0 ) ) The zero is because you want an exact match. You could also use an IFERROR for the upcoming months so they don't show an error

Answer (score 1):

in the code pane of your "monthly report Sheet" worksheet place the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.address = "$G$3" Then Range("F21:F29").Value = Worksheets("YEAR sheet").Range("D21:D29").Offset(, Month(Range("G3"))).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: you are welcome. if this is the solution you'll adopt then you may want to mark answer as accepted. thank you